# Adding RTL support to mobile application

Tags: android, ruby, mobile, right-to-left

How to add RTL-"right to left" input support to a ruby on rhodes mobile application.

I am trying to add support for Arabic language in my cross platform ruby app. so far unable to get input text in RTL. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please add a few more details. As in: what you mean by "input" text? What you have tried so far? An example of what you are hoping to achieve? [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I found the solution at google android api. <http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html